# How to generate C++ library with xerces for specific XML

Tags: c++, xml, xerces

I've gone through [this xerces C++ tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/XML-Xerces-C.html), which shows how you might write a nice C++ class that allows you to access your data from the XML using simple function calls. The problem is that 200 lines of C++ seems like excessive amount of work just to grab a couple pieces of data from an XML file. I am hoping to find something that will take in my XML file and spit out C++. I have tried to search for solutions online to generate this for me but I can't find anything.